# Python UDF for Apache Pig failing

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig, jython, user-defined-functions

I'm doing a homework task using Pig. I've computed all he needed values, but I need to output them in a specific format, so I wrote a UDF in Python.
It is passed a bag of tuples `{(id: int,tfidf: double)}` (documentation for pig doesn't specify exactly how this would look for Python, but from examples I guess that it's an iterable of tuples) and it returns a `chararray`. The actual code is:

```
@outputSchema('doclist:chararray')
def format_list(docs):
  outs = []
  for docid, tfidf in docs:
    outs.append('{0}:{1}'.format(docid, tfidf))
  return '\t'.join(outs)
```

It is called from

```
tfidf = FOREACH (GROUP tfsWithNDocs BY token) {
    idf = LOG((double)totaldocs.total / (double)ndocs);
    ranked = FOREACH tfsWithNDocs GENERATE id, tf * idf AS tfidf;
    ordered = ORDER ranked BY tfidf DESC;
    relevant = LIMIT ordered 20;
    GENERATE group AS token, funs.format_list(relevant) AS relevant;
};
```

When I run the script, it fails with:

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Error executing function
    at org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonFunction.exec(JythonFunction.java:120)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:337)
    ... (several hadoop calls)
```

No hints about actual Python exception.

If I don't pass the data to my UDF and just store it as a bag, everything works.

What could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `format`. Replacing it with old-style `%` formatting allowed the script to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework I won't give you the full answer but I would suggest that you look carefully at your outputSchema and review [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@pig.apache.org/msg06404.html).

Comment: Actually, homework isn't about this pretty-printing, it's about computing TF-IDF on hadoop. I'm just trying to make the code prettier.

Also, I don't see any problems with my schema. This is a function which returns a single string. Or should it return a single-element tuple to be used in a GENERATE expression?